# Error When I deploy Application Page

Tags: sharepoint-server

I got an error when I deploy "Application Page" by Visual Studio 2015 to SharePoint Server 2016 below:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': The value of the argument '16' is an unsupported enum type. Parameter name: verCompatLevel